# log4j.properties doesn't work correctly on wildfly

Tags: java, logging, log4j, wildfly

I have a log4j.properties file in the classpath.

It was found at the location APP/XX.jar/log4j.properties.

And I noticed that in the ear file I can also find log4j-1.2.17.jar in lib folder.

But whatever I wrote in the log4j.properties file, they were ignored. Like:

```
log4j.rootCategory=WARN
```

Or something like this:

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, A1
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.logger.org.springframework=WARN
```

But all of the loggings will still be printed on the server.

Did I configure them wrong or has my Wildfly this property file igored?

Comment: Well, of course they will be printed on the server. That's where the program is running on. The servers often redirect the console output to a file anyways, so that may not help much. What is the actual problem you're having? Are you not getting any log output?

Comment: @Kayaman Hi, I would like to hide all INFOs, but read WARNs and ERRORs and Stdouts. But now I still see all of the INFOs and of course other ouputs. What should I do? Thanks:)

Comment: Have you considered moving the properties inside the EAR (but outside the JAR) as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given the location of the properties file it is ignored. If the log4j.properties file is in the `EAR/META-INF` directory then WildFly will attempt to configure log4j for you. It's suggested not to use a `ConsoleAppender` though as it could result in deadlocks due to the appender attempting to write to `System.out` and `System.out` being wrapped in WildFly.

Given the configuration this leaves you with three options.

1. Change the value of [`add-logging-api-dependencies`](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Logging+Configuration#LoggingConfiguration-%7B%7Baddloggingapidependencies%7D%7D) to `false`.
2. Add a [`jboss-deployment-structure.xml`](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/How+To#HowTo-HowdoIusemyownversionoflog4j%3F) and disable the logging subsystem on your deployment
3. Configure logging via the logging subsystem. This can be done either globally or via a [logging-profile](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Logging+Configuration#LoggingConfiguration-LoggingProfiles).